# Weight loss stopped (even gaining a bit weight)

Tags: weight-loss, diet

I've started excercising and following diet to lose weight this January. I weigh 110 kilogramms now, and I was somewhere around 125 before. I've lost the first 10 kgs in one month, now nearly nothing, it totally stopped. I'm usually eating 60-80g of carbohydrates and 140g protein, which comes from chicken, fish, vegetables, and fruits. I take absolutely no sugar, and no wheat. I excercise 2-3 times a week, one hour of jumpy-runny kind of cardio (no more time for that).

I'm a little confused about a lot of things:

- some articles say that I should take more carbs because my body is starving, but they are also calculating with more excercise, if I'd stick with 100-140 gramms, I'd literally eat the same meals like before I started
- they also mention that I need at least one gramm of protein per 1kg of body weight, but some say that per lean body mass, which is about 60 gramms, considering that ~50% of my body is fat (if the measuring device is correct)
- nearly every source states that 5-6 meals a day is the best for losing weight, but I'm not sure that then the glycogen breakdown even starts?
- I've been thinking about following the ketogenic diet as well, but I'm not sure if the amount of fat it advises is good for me? I mean if I don't really count calories, only carbs, it's all right?
- if not, how much calories should I take, and how is that broken down into carbs, protein, and fat?

Thank you really-really much in advance!

Comment: From the figures you gave us (140g protein, 80g carbs) you are eating 880 calories. How many calories are you getting from fat? (No, fat does not make you fat) Someone of your size would definitely need at least 2000 calories for weight loss. Is there a reason you do cardio over weight lifting?

Comment: As I calculated I take about 1300-1700 calories a day (70-80g fat), depending on my meals. My joints are in a bad condition, and my doctor recommended me not to do weight lifting, only "use" my own weight. According to Fitbit, cardio also burns more calories than weight lifting.

Comment: How tall are you? 1300 calories will definitely trigger the "starvation mode" of your body as a male and 1700 may trigger it. Seeing as your joints are in bad condition, avoid running and jumping as the impact can be really tough on the joint. (Technique may affect this, I'm not sure) Biking, swimming and elliptical may be better alternative.

Comment: @akadian "1300 calories will definitely trigger the starvation mode" completely incorrect, the subjects in the famous study were **actually** starving, not on some manageable fat-loss diet, 1300 is not low enough to trigger this. See: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11010936

Comment: @JJosaur Fair point, I guess I had no source other that hearsay about 1500 calories being when "starvation mode" start. It is still insanely low for a person of his size however.

Comment: Thanks for the comments as well, I didn't realize that starvation mode comes that easy.

Comment: It says in the experiment that the diet was between 7000-11000 kJ/d which equals to 1673.04 calories at the lower end. This is more than the OP is claiming to eat, so I would say there study is relevant to this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some articles say that I should take more carbs because my body is starving, but they are also calculating with more excercise, if I'd stick with 100-140 gramms, I'd literally eat the same meals like before I started

Not sure what you're confused about here. What they mean is, when you initially start a diet, don't all of a sudden cut out all carbs because your metabolism will slow down. This is because carbs are muscle sparing, and without carbs for energy, you will at some point lose muscle, if you lose muscle, your metabolism slows down and you don't burn nearly as many calories, hence why your weight loss came to a stop. When you DO eat carbs, make sure you eat them right around your workouts and or around the morning, since this is when you are most insulin sensitive and least likely to store carbs as fat.

> they also mention that I need at least one gramm of protein per 1kg of body weight, but some say that per lean body mass, which is about 60 gramms, considering that ~50% of my body is fat (if the measuring device is correct)

first of all, this should be 0.8-1.5g of protein per LBS of body weight (not kg), and no, this doesn't depend on lean body mass, although it would be more important, the more muscle you have. Protein is absolutely essential for fat loss since it is the hardest macro to turn into fat, has high thermogenesis (your body burns more calories during breakdown), spares your muscles and provokes protein synthesis (good for metabolism), makes you feel full and more...make sure you get at least 0.8g per lbs of bodyweight.DON'T listen to anything else, this lean body mass thing you heard does not apply here, eat as much protein as possible without going over your caloric limit.

> nearly every source states that 5-6 meals a day is the best for losing weight, but I'm not sure that then the glycogen breakdown even starts?

This is one of the biggest myths in nutrition, you do NOT need to eat 5-6 meals a day. People think that since eating meals has thermogenic effects on metabolism, then the more often you eat, the more calories you burn. This is NOT true, there's lots of studies disproving this (the amount u eat is proportional to thermogenesis not frequency). The reason 5-6 meals is usually suggested is because it is easier to divide your macro intakes into 5-6 rather than 3 big meals. Also, eating frequently will make you feel full more often. However, you mention glycogen breakdown and you are actually right. The more often you eat, the less you're in a fasted state and hence the less time your body has to breakdown carbs for energy (i.e you won't reach fat breakdown since youre constantly breaking down carbs), and this is why I said eat your carbs around your workout and not any other time if you're actually SERIOUS about fat loss. This means before and after the workout (1-2 hours withing both). A good approach would be to eat breakfast, lunch, preworkout meal with carbs, post workout with carbs, then dinner...this way you have lots of time between meals to burn fat while burning carbs for the workout and not muscle.

> I've been thinking about following the ketogenic diet as well, but I'm not sure if the amount of fat it advises is good for me? I mean if I don't really count calories, only carbs, it's all right?

This isn't the question that you should ask yourself.  Ketogenic diet has its benefits and downsides. It's hard to follow but will give you results. However, if you care about your gym performance, it is not the best. If you really care about fat loss, keto works...no questions about it. The amount of fat is obviously really high since that's the definition of keto but assuming you get your fats from healthy sources like eggs and avacado it's fine.

> if not, how much calories should I take, and how is that broken down into carbs, protein, and fat?

You weigh 110kg, so that's around 242lbs. Your RMR is probably around 3000 calories as a result, and thus if you are consuming 3000-600 = 2400 ish calories daily every day consistenly, you will be in a caloric deficit and hence lose weight. Of this, 1g per lbs of bodyweight from protein means 242lbs x 4 = 968 calories from protein, and the fat and carbs are upto you to manipulate. A good rule is to let fats be 20% of your caloric intake and the rest from carbs. If this isn't working, then you slowly dial the fats up while tuning the carbs down. Your body is unique to you and hence you will have to experiment a bit to find out what works for you. If after a few week 2400 calories isn't resulting in fat loss, then you simply reduce this number by 100-200 and repeat..it is THAT simple, what is not so simple, is being dedicated and sticking to it.

As to why you gained weight, you simply decreased calories too much. To the extent that your body had to adapt by slowing your metabolism down. If your metabolism is down you burn less calories, so if you stayed on the same diet, your caloric excess would have increased more than before. Furthermore, you probably lost some muscle as well which would mean your metabolism slowed down as a result once again. As with everything, make gradual adjustments next time and you'll be fine in a short period of time.

Comment: Wow...I just...didn't expect such a long and thorough answer. Thank you very very very much!

Comment: Yea no problem, I've been there too, let me know if you need anything else.